# Defining generic property in abstract class as a type of the implementing class

Tags: java, c#, generics

Let's say I have a class like:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public List<TypeOfImplementingClassHere> container;
}
```

So when another class implements it, say, like so:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar(List<Bar> container) {
        this.container = container;
    }
}
```

We can have a pointer to the container in which we find our `Bar` object. Can you do this in Java or C#?

Comment: Umm... can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? That code doesn't make any sense (granted, not a Java dev)

Comment: This question was edited to be `Java` related a month and a half after it was asked. My answer below was when this was tagged and asked as a `C#` question .. I assume thats why you've now, just today .. downvoted it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead downvoted because it doesn't solve the problem. I've had this one around for a while and just now solved it. Whether Java or C# it doesn't matter—there's a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

Try this.

```
public abstract class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {

    public List<T> container;

    protected Foo() {
        enforceConstraints();
    }

    private void enforceConstraints() {
        boolean valid = true;
        try {
            valid =
                ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[0]
                    .equals(
                        this.getClass()
                    );
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!valid) {
            String name = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
            throw new IllegalImplementationException(
                    name + " must be declared as "+ "\"class " + name + " extends Foo<"+name+">\"");
        }
    }

    private static class IllegalImplementationException extends RuntimeException {
        IllegalImplementationException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

it's even simpler in C#:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Foo<T> {

    public List<T> container;

    protected Foo() {
        enforceConstraints();
    }

    private void enforceConstraints() {
        if (!this.GetType().Equals(typeof(T))) {
            String name = this.GetType().Name;      
            throw new IllegalImplementationException(
                name + " must be declared as " + "\"class " + name + " : Foo<" + name + ">\"");
        }
    }


}

public class IllegalImplementationException : Exception {
    public IllegalImplementationException(String message) : base(message) {}
}
```

`enforceConstraints()` can be removed when sent to production. Note that this enforces that a generic parameter is bounded in our way via reflection because the type bounds needed here aren't available in Java or C#. Because we're enforcing a constraint entirely with reflection, it isn't necessary to add the constraint `T extends Foo<T>`, but this can prevent misuse. Note that with with the constraints `Foo<T extends Foo<T>` you can have `Bar1 extends Foo<Bar1>` and `Bar2 extends Foo<Bar1>`, though we don't want the second type, hence why reflection is necessary.